# Trouble with overlaying images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to overlay 5 images that are all the same size, namely 614 w x 814 h. Because parts of each image are transparent, together they make one whole picture. I can't use my original images to show you because they've got personal data on them. Instead I used color blocks to show you an example I've made.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kxcrr0h/)

I'm trying to center all of the images in the center of the screen, and it's crucial that they remain there, no matter how far the browser is zoomed in, or if the window is resized. To do that, I use this code per image:

```
#blue{
margin-top: 10%; 
padding-left: 0;
padding-right: 0;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: block;
width: 33%;
height: 100%;
}
```

**My question is:** How do I center these 5 images in the middle of the screen, having all them overlay eachother like so; blue < green < purple < yellow < red. And still keep them positioned so that there's no space between each image, so that they may form one block of five different colors?

Is there an easier, more accurate way of doing this than what I've shown you in the fiddle?

Comment: So you want them all in a single row? Or do you just want the whitespace removed? Can you create an image of the desired result?

Comment: Put them all in a single div and center ***that***

Comment: That doesn't solve what I'm experiencing as an issue. I was thinking of the z index property maybe being a better alternative? Would you know how to use that?

Comment: If you would take a look at his fiddle it quite clear what he is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution. I used this code per color block, which was what I needed

```
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Yep! */
  width: 48%;
  height: 59%;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Put them all in a single div and center that -  Paulie_D

Cenctered container with image(s).

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.container img:nth-of-type(1) {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/100/100" />
  <!--place images here!-->
</div>
```